# Jquery select option

Tags: select, html-select

I'm quite new to jQuery and was wondering how i could select an options in a dropdown select menu.

To be more specific:
You can select a color in the dropdown menu and when you click on the button the background color changes to that color.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="form-box">
        <h1>Funky Background Color Changer</h1>
        <p>1. Choose a funky background color:
            <select name="bgColor" id="">
                <option value="$juicy-cyan">Juicy Cyan</option>
                <option value="$purdy-purple">Purdy Purple</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>2. That's it actually! Just click the button.</p><br>
        <button class="funk">Let's Funk!</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ID to your `h1` and your colors (Hex values) on the values of the selected list for example, then set the brackground when the button it's clicked:

**Html**

```
<div id="form-box">
        <h1 id="h1_id">Funky Background Color Changer</h1>
        <p>1. Choose a funky background color:
            <select name="bgColor" id="bgColor_id">
                <option value="#ff0000">Juicy Cyan</option>
                <option value="#0066ff">Purdy Purple</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>2. That's it actually! Just click the button.</p><br>
        <button class="funk" id="submitButton">Let's Funk!</button>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function () {
    var color = $("#bgColor_id").val();
    $("#h1_id").css('background-color', color);
});
```

Comment: can i use SASS variables instead of the colors hex?

Comment: @JordanHeuten Never worked with SASS, so can't help you with that. But try to replace the hex values with the sass variables and see the result.

Comment: the background color doesnt seem to change tho

Answer (score 0):

At first you should give select an id attribute that jQuery could access. For example you could use same as name bgColor. Than code would be:

```
$('#bgColor').val()
```